# How to architect a solution where one Lambda writes to S3 on a timer and another Lambda reads from it on demand

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We need to implement two Lambdas, one writes a file to S3 and another reads that file.  "write" Lambda is on a timer, "read" Lambda is on demand.  Not sure about best practices and options to synchronize these independent processes. Please advise on some options.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information about _why_ you wish to do this? There might be a better option! Also, what do you mean by "is on demand" — do you mean it will run when a user requests it? What have you tried so far, and what difficulties have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is directly supported by AWS, so the setup is simple:

Configure the first Lambda to be [triggered on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html).

Configure the second Lambda to be [triggered by S3 new object notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

Comment: Thank you!  Please note that the second “read” Lambda will be triggered on demand by external users.  In our case such requests will be coming via the API Gateway.  These requests will generate large response files, possibly exceeding the max timeout on the API Gateway.  This is why we need the other Lambda to cache the file in S3 and have it served from there.  However, it is possible that the request for the file comes when the file is being generated.

Comment: @user897210 that's certainly a lot of detail that you left out of your original question. I'm not sure Lambda+API Gateway for the response handling is the best architecture since that would timeout after 29 seconds.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I wrote that the read Lambda was “on demand” thinking that would describe the basic scenario of the file being requested while it is being generated by the other Lambda.  Very much open to suggestions about how to handle this, please feel free to share your thoughts on alternative architectures.